# .htaccess or using php, How to redirect the site if device is a mobile, tab or any handy devices

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I want to redirect the page if the user is using mobile from

**https://example.com**

to

**https://example.com/mobile/.**

please suggest me `php` or `.htaccess` code

Comment: You should at least show us what you've tried yourself. Saying "I didn't try anything. Fix it for me." shows you just don't care...

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` will tell you the user's browser. The best course of action is a responsive web design. PERIOD.

Comment: i have tried using javascript to redirect according to the device width and both the sites are different so responsive web design is not the option for me

Comment: Please read before asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask,   always you can edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://mobiledetect.net/

Using this you can check quite easily whether it is mobile or not.

```
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

// Check for any mobile device.
if ($detect->isMobile())
   header('Location: https://example.com/mobile');
else
   // other content for desktop
```